# Angularjs google maps marker and panTo don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I've this controller to set or get position on google maps by inserting address or get position from browser/mobile localization:

```
//MAPPE
.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $ionicModal, $compile, $timeout) { 
      $scope.init = function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.9100711,12.5359979);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        $scope.markers = [];
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
      }

        $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
        if(!$scope.map) {return;}
        $ionicLoading.show({
          template: 'Cerco la posizione...',
          showBackdrop: false
        });

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
          $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
          var marker = new google.maps.Circle({
                strokeColor: '#F90',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FC0',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: $scope.map,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                radius: 100
            });
            marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">Tu sei qui</div>';
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>LA TUA POSIZIONE</h2>Questo è il punto indicato dal tuo GPS!</br>Se ci sono errori clicca sul punsante in basso a destra e scrivi il tuo indirizzo');
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
            });
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $scope.markers.push(marker);

        }, function(error) {
          alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
        });
    };

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/position.html', {scope: $scope}).then(function(modal) {$scope.modal = modal});
    $scope.closePosition = function() {$scope.modal.hide()};
    $scope.searchPoint = function() {$scope.modal.show()};

    $scope.doPosition = function() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById('indirizzo').value;
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
            var latiSearch = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lonSearch = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latiSearch, lonSearch));
            var marker = new google.maps.Circle({
                strokeColor: '#F90',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FC0',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: $scope.map,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(latiSearch, lonSearch),
                radius: 100
            });
            $scope.map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
            marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">Tu sei qui</div>';
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>'+address+'</h2>Questo è l\'indirizzo che hai indicato.</br> Ti ricordiamo che NESSUNO potrà vedere in dettaglio dove ti trovi, ma avrà solo un\'indicazione approssimativa in chilometri!');
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
            });
            $scope.markers.push(marker);
            $scope.map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
            $scope.closePosition();
        } else {alert('La geolocalizzazione non è andata a buon fine: ' + status)}
        });
        $timeout(function(){$scope.closePosition()}, 1000)
    }
})
```

All works fine, but when position is taken or address inserted, and marker created, I receive this error:

```
TypeError: marker.getPosition is not a function
------> $scope.map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
```

So panTo dont work!
Where is my error???

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting getPosition is undefined is because, according to the docs, it does not exist, [here's the link.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle)

**The root of the problem is actually** that you are passing the wrong objects to `$scope.map.panTo();`. [Please refer to the google website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) for panTo on the Map class, you must pass it the same type of object it is expecting in the parameters.

`panTo(latLng:LatLng|LatLngLiteral);` This is saying that it excepts a parameter of either an instance of the LatLng class or LatLngLiteral class, not the Circle instance that you are creating above.

[Here's the reference to LatLng.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

To fix your code above you can change from this:

```
$scope.map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
```

to this

```
$scope.map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(latiSearch, lonSearch));
```

I'd also recommend to store the instance you are already creating above for `$scope.map.setCenter()` to the same one you will be using here.